# Dynamic variable echo inside $_POST['']

Tags: php, post, echo, dynamic-variables

I have a form that has radio inputs that have a dynamically generated name like below:

```
<input type="number" name="<?php echo date("Y")-4 ?>brand%gross" placeholder="Gross Sales % for <?php echo date("Y")-4 ?>">
<input type="number" name="<?php echo date("Y")-3 ?>brand%gross" placeholder="Gross Sales % for <?php echo date("Y")-3 ?>">
<input type="number" name="<?php echo date("Y")-2 ?>brand%gross" placeholder="Gross Sales % for <?php echo date("Y")-2 ?>">
<input type="number" name="<?php echo date("Y")-1 ?>brand%gross" placeholder="Gross Sales % for <?php echo date("Y")-1 ?>">
```

Then the form is processed and creates a dynamic table with all the values the user inputs that is then emailed to me. My question is how do I get dynamically generated radios to output to the table that is sent? I know the below isn't correct but just to give you a better look at what I'm trying to do:

```
if( isset($_POST) ){
    ${ echo date("Y")-4 } = $_POST['{ echo date("Y")-4 }];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: dynamic table? Do you mean rows created based on the radios selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By have a string (the output of `date()`) from which you subtract and integer, you end up casting the result as an integer, not a string.  You are probably better off making the string correctly to begin with and getting rid of the integer arithmetic issue.

I would suggest working with DateTime objects. Here's how you might output you input fields.

```
<?php
$current_date = new DateTime();
while($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $date_int = new DateInterval('P' . (string)$i . 'Y');
    $temp_date = $current_date->sub($date_int);
    $date_string = $temp_date->format('Y');
?>
    <input type="number" name="<?php echo $date_string; ?>brand%gross" placeholder="Gross Sales % for <?php echo $date_string; ?>" /> 
<?php
} // end while
?>
```

When processing the `$_POST` you can do similar:

```
<?php
$current_date = new DateTime();
$year_array = array();
while($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $date_int = new DateInterval('P' . (string)$i . 'Y');
    $temp_date = $current_date->sub($date_int);
    $date_string = $temp_date->format('Y');
    if (!empty($_POST[$date_string. 'brand%gross'])) {
        $year_array[$date_string] = $_POST[$date_string . 'brand%gross'];
    }
} // end while    
?>
```

Note that I use an array to store your data indexed by year string , as you can't have a variable name that starts with a number (i.e. `$2013nrand%gross` is not valid).

I would also STRONGLY suggest using array access notation in your inputs to simply things.

If you made each input like this:

```
<input type="number" name="year_brand_gross[<?php echo $date_string; ?>]" placeholder="Gross Sales % for <?php echo $date_string; ?>" />
```

Then the names of `year_brand_gross[2013]` and such would automatically get populated as an array into `$_POST['year_brand_gross']`, eliminating the need to loop through the POST input.

Instead you could set this to a variable like this

```
if(!empty($_POST['year_brand_gross']) {
    $year_array = $_POST['year_brand_gross'];
}
```

For PHP < 5.3.0 you can use alternate method to generate the year strings:

```
$current_date = new DateTime();
for ($i = 1; $i <=4; $i++) {
    $current_date->modify('-1 year');
    $date_string = $current_date->format('Y');
    // other code here
}
```

Note that, as shown, this will alter the value of `$current_date` with each iteratoin, which differs from the first solution.

Comment: When trying to implement your example I'm getting an error on the 3rd line of your first block of code.

Comment: What error are you getting?  What version of PHP are you using, as DateInterval requires PHP >= 5.3.0?

Comment: Just getting a parse error. The version may be the problem... I know I'm running at least 5. I'll have to check and get back to you Monday. Really appreciate the help, Mike!

Comment: @ItsMIllerTime65 I updated the with an alternative approach for PHP < 5.3

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a varible content inside $_POST, well... Use a variable.

```
$foo = date("Y")-4;
$_POST['str'] = $foo;
```

So... the thing is , you want to use a variable variable name that might go like this:

```
$foo = date("Y")-4;
$$foo = $_POST[$foo];
```

Got it?

EDIT 1:

So that the variable won't start with a number:

```
$bar = "dt_";
$foo = date("Y")-4;
${$bar.$foo} = $_POST[$foo];
```

Comment: Um, I think you've got a typo in `$$foo`. ;-)

Comment: don't think so... It is a double "$", thats why its variable variable, cause its name is variable.

Comment: Hm... interesting. I didn't know that. `One learns something new every day`.

Comment: You could use ${$foo} too , I really don't know the difference, but people seem to prefer it.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I'll look into that. I remember seeing something related to a similar syntax and there is a purpose, but can't remember off the top of my head right now. Cheers

Comment: It is fine to point out the use of variable variables, however that will not work in this case, as variable name can't being with a number.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Gio, but Mike is right... I can't use a variable variable because it would start with a number.

Comment: Yes , you got a point there. For the sake of information I'll just add that you can use : ${$base.$suffix} = $_POST[$foo]; As in $base = "date_"; and $suffix = date("Y")-4; I'll just add to my reply.

Answer (score 0):

First off you want to update you html so that the names of the fields

```
<input type="number" name="year[<?= date("Y")-4 ?>brand%gross]" placeholder="Gross Sales % for <?= date("Y")-4 ?>">
<input type="number" name="year[<?= date("Y")-3 ?>brand%gross]" placeholder="Gross Sales % for <?= date("Y")-3 ?>">
<input type="number" name="year[<?= date("Y")-2 ?>brand%gross]" placeholder="Gross Sales % for <?= date("Y")-2 ?>">
<input type="number" name="year[<?= date("Y")-1 ?>brand%gross]" placeholder="Gross Sales % for <?= date("Y")-1 ?>">
```

In your PHP you will be able to access the elements by there keys

```
$val2010 = $_POST["year"]["2010brand%gross"];
```